# Why is blur event not fired in iOS Safari Mobile (iPhone / iPad)?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, ipad

I've two event handlers bound to an anchor tag: one for focus and blur.

The handlers fire on desktop, but in iphone and ipad only focus is fired correctly. Blur is not fired if I click outside the anchor tag (blur fires only when I click some other form elements in the page):

```
    $("a").focus(function(){
        console.log("focus fired");
    });

    $("a").blur(function(){
        console.log("blur fired");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<form>
    <a href="#">test link</a>
    <div>
    <input type="text" title="" size="38" value="" id="lname1" name="" class="text">
    </div>
    <div style="padding:100px">
        <p>test content</p>
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an anchor has any events attached, the first tap on it in iOS causes the anchor to be put into the hover state, and focused. A tap away removes the hover state, but the link remains focused. This is by design. To properly control an application on iOS, you need to implement touch-based events and react to those instead of desktop ones.

There is [a complete guide to using Javascript events in WebKit on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

Comment: I Found one more intresting thing in the https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html, that only when i click the clickable element than only the anchor tag lost focus.

Comment: I've read the posted guide and still don't see how you detect when an input element has lost focus? Can you please post a code example?

Comment: @ChrisFox Sorry, I don't have any code examples. You have to tap on another form element to transfer focus (and get a blur event on the previous one).

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with touch devices you can use the **touchleave** or **touchend** event to handle when the user clicks outside the area.

```
$("a").on('touchleave touchcancel', function () {
      // do something
});
```

For this to work you need to update your focus function to listen for an on **click** event as follows

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
      if(e.handled !== true) {
            e.handled = true
      } else {
            return false
      }
      // do something
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but you can get .blur to fire by registering a click handler on every DOM element. This removes focus from the previously focused element.

```
$('*').click();
$('html').css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
```

The second line removes the highlight when elements are clicked.

I know this is sub-optimal, but it may get you going.

Comment: Don't target every element on the page like this. This spins up a listener for every. Single. Dom. Element. It is horrible for performance.

Answer (score 2):

I have check all the doc in the @NicholasShanks answer, but a little frustrated testing all the events.

Android and iOS:

- Tested on **Android** Samsung S9
- Tested on **iOS** iPad 5ºgen

Finally i have got a solution:
Seems iPad listen to mouseout as blur, and seems android listen perfectly to the blur event,  i just add a ternary on this case to attach the right event (previously i have aimed to a mobile or tablet device instead of a computer.

```js
// element >> element you want to trigger
// os >> function that return operative system 'ios' or 'android' in my case

element.addEventListener(os === 'ios' ? 'mouseout' : 'blur', () => {
  // Do something
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `blur` event does not fire because when you click outside the anchor tag on a non-clickable element, iOS ignores the click (and the `click` event does not fire).

There are a couple of threads regarding this (e.g. [.click event not firing in Chrome on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146889/click-event-not-firing-in-chrome-on-ios)). You can fix it by adding `cursor: pointer` to the `<body>` or some other element that the click will be performed on.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I've found is to just make document.body "clickable" at page initialization time:

```
document.body.onclick = function() {};
```

Then a click anywhere will blur the active element, just like on a desktop browser. Tested on iOS 15.3.1.