# .click event not firing in Chrome on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome

I'm using the following code to show a drop down menu on my site when a user clicks on the menu bar on a mobile device.

```
$('#mobile-menu').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

It works fine on the desktop browsers, and in Safari on iOS, but in Chrome on iOS it does nothing.

The weird thing is if that I click on the options icon in Chrome and request the desktop version then the site looks exactly the same but the menu bar now works.

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else running into this issue - iOS Chrome checks for one of two things before firing the `.click` event. You can choose either of these, or if you are paranoid, you can also opt for **both**.

1. The element must have the CSS property: `cursor:pointer;` or,

   - **EDIT:** an interesting quirk to be aware of: if your `cursors:pointer;` rule is only inside a media query, iOS Chrome won't trigger the click event either. Just make sure that you have a CSS Rule for that element that includes `cursor:pointer;` outside of the media query in this case, or alternatively, look at the second option below.
2. The element needs an `onclick=""` attribute.

   - *Side Note:* the `onclick` attribute can be blank (assuming you want to target/work with the event inside your own *.js* file), as long as it's there. See Example 2.

---

## Example 1 - CSS

This is by far the neatest/nicest way to fix the problem. Make sure your CSS contains the following:

```
#mobile-menu {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

## Example 2 - HTML Attribute

Whilst not as nice as the CSS solution, this has yet to fail the few times I've had to use it.

Make sure your HTML markup contains the `onclick` attribute like this:

```
<div id="mobile-menu" onclick=""> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use tap event instead of click event. It may work

```
$('#mobile-menu').tap(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('open');
    $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, although does involve loading jquery mobile, do you think there's any way of doing it without that.