# blur function didn't work on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, onblur

I am developping a responsive app. My problem is why the 'blur' function didn't work on iOS devices?

here is an example of code that didn't work on iOS mobile devices but works on Android and desktop.

```
 var a = $('<a href="javascript:return false;" title="'+ListeTypes.jsonData[i].title+'" id="typ'+i+'"> </a>');
a.on("click", function(event){
             $(this).parent().css('background-color','#ff0080');
                 getCarouselItemsList(ListeTypes.jsonData[i].uRL);
                }); 
a.focus(function() {
                    $(this).parent().css('background-color','#ff0080');
                });
a.on('blur', function() {
                  $(this).parent().css('background-color','#00c6c6');
                });
```

So "a" is a dynamically created button in a ul li list. I have tested a lot of events (such as addEventListener....) but I didn't get it to work until now.
Please I need your helps. Any ideas please?

Thank you so much for your precious answers.

Comment: I don't see any `blur` event in your code

Comment: you are right! I have edited the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blur Event Not Fired Properly in ios of ipad and iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492881/blur-event-not-fired-properly-in-ios-of-ipad-and-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining the focus color on CSS and in the JS I just triggered the element to be focus. So I didn't need the 'blur' event.