# Blur event not firing on IPad and IPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I have the following JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtField1').on('blur', function () {
        alert("Field1");
     }

}
```

The code has been designed with an emphasis on being responsive.
The blur event fires on all browsers and works well on all devices except IPAD and IPhone on the safari browser.

On IPad and IPhone over the safari browser when we touch the `txtField1` a keyboard opens up. We typed in "abc" on the keyboard into `txtField1` then we clicked on `txtField2` but the blur event does not fire.

The blur event fires only if we click the done button on the popped up keyboard.
How do we overcome this. How can we make the blur event fire even if we click anywhere outside `txtField1` even if we do not click the done button on the keyboard.

Thank you,
Gmat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is blur event not fired in iOS Safari Mobile (iPhone / iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492881/why-is-blur-event-not-fired-in-ios-safari-mobile-iphone-ipad)

Comment: I tried touchleave and touchend neither of these events work. Is there a library i need to download for these events to work?