# Blur event on iPhoneXR Safari browser

Tags: iphone, angular, blur

I have an input and have a function that is called on blur event in Angular 7.

In iPhone browser (Safari), when I tap outside the input box, the event doesn't get fired, however it works well on Chrome. What could be the reason?

**It is exclusively for an input type only and not an `<a>` type**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is blur event not fired in iOS Safari Mobile (iPhone / iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492881/why-is-blur-event-not-fired-in-ios-safari-mobile-iphone-ipad)

Comment: @Florian I cant use such thing throughout the site. I have more than 10 forms.